# Headset mic not being used

Tags: asus, microphone, headphones, headset

I have an ASUS 1015E laptop that has a single 3.5mm audio combo port for both mic and headphone (TRRS connector plugs go in there). So I use headsets that come in a single wire which has both headphone and mic functionality. (Like the ones that come with smartphones).

This headset works perfect on windows where the integrated mic of the laptop is disabled in lieu of the headset's mic whenever it is connected. However, that's not the case on my Ubuntu 13.10 (x86_64).

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing the upstream kernel 3.17-rc1 fixed my issue.

Here's the launchpad bug that I filed regarding this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1359803

Answer (score 0):

First install gnome-media as shown below-

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-media
```

then use -

```
gstreamer-properties
```

Change the default Input ,Close the gstreamer-properties and connect your mic to check.

hope it will work..if did not try-

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

after installing it , open it and go to `configuration tab` and select `analog Stero Duplex` under `Input device tab` press mute button to unmute, or let it be if already unmuted..

Comment: None of the audio inputs there seem to select the headphone's mic.. all I hear is sound coming from the mic from my monitor screen (integrated mic) when I click "test".

Comment: It is already in analog Stereo Duplex under configuration. The input device tab still responds only to the integrated mic.. :( I tried everything.

Comment: Update and upgrade shows nothing since I have everything up to date. I'm using Saucy (13.10) and not lucid. Also `linux-backports-modules-alsa-lucid-generic` is not found.

Comment: thats wat all i have, leave the comments and answer here , some one else can get information what you have done..

Answer (score -1):

Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`

And add this line at the end of opened file

```
options snd_hda_intel model=laptop-dmic
```